# Кнопка вверх/вниз javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите как реализовать на сайте кнопку, при нажатии на которую скролл на сайте будет ехать вниз, а при повторном нажатии на нее же, скролл будет ехать вверх. Пример: www.magnatek.ru ( прямо на главной есть кнопка "Еще о компании" )

Пробовал через toggleClass, но не вышло, может я делал неправильно.

Comment: [Кнопка вверх вниз на javascript. Кнопка наверх. Кнопка вниз. Скролинг страницы на javascript.][1]


  [1]: http://javascript.ru/node/12150

Comment: Ну она же не должна убираться/появляться. Это фиксированная кнопка.

Comment: @yet1111 вообщем подбирайте http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%2F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7+javascript&lr=213

Answer (score 1):

UPD: http://jsfiddle.net/ut3rx/

на сайте из вашего примера все есть:

```
<a href="#" class="more_about_company"><span class="more_about_companyi"></span></a>

function scrollToEl(elem){
    var num = elem.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: num
    }, 500);
};

function chooseScroll(elem, elemBottom){
    var curTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var delimetr = curTop + ($(window).height()/2);
    var elemTopNum = elem.offset().top;
    if(delimetr < elemTopNum){
        scrollToEl(elemBottom);
    }
    else {
        scrollToScreen(elemBottom);
    }
}
 $('.more_about_company').on('click', function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    chooseScroll(elem, $('.more_about_company_wrap'));
    return false;
});
```

или обязательно JavaScript?

Comment: >или обязательно JavaScript?

это по вашему не javascript ?

Comment: Не получается у меня сделать рабочую версии этой кнопки с их скриптом.

Comment: >  или обязательно JavaScript?
>это по вашему не javascript ?
@eicto имеется ввиду чистый js, а у АО jquery

Comment: на чистом js это вообще не получится делать, т.к. чистый js не умеет DOM

Comment: @eicto может я ошибаюсь, но вроде document.getElementById('aa').style.background = "black" это уже DOM?

Comment: @eicto я имел ввиду без jQuery

Comment: @danpetruk да это расширение DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-нибудь полезно будет. Написал на `javascript`, без `jQuery`.

```js
/* begin Up-Down button  */
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var upDownBtn = document.querySelector('.up_down_btn');
  var check;

  function trackScroll() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    var coords = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (scrolled > coords) {
      upDownBtn.classList.add('up_down_btn-show');
      upDownBtn.innerHTML = '&uarr;';
      upDownBtn.setAttribute('title', 'Наверх');
      check = false;
    }
    if (scrolled === 0) {
      upDownBtn.innerHTML = '&darr;';
      upDownBtn.setAttribute('title', 'Вниз');
      check = true;
    }
  }

  function backToTop() {
    upDownBtn.classList.add('up_down_btn-disabled');
    if (!check) {
      (function goTop() {

        if (window.pageYOffset !== 0) {
          window.scrollBy(0, -80);
          setTimeout(goTop, 0);
        } else {
          upDownBtn.classList.remove('up_down_btn-disabled');
        }

      })();
      return;

    } else if (check) {
      (function goBottom() {
        var match = Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight);

        if (match != document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
          window.scrollBy(0, 80);
          setTimeout(goBottom, 0);
        } else {
          upDownBtn.classList.remove('up_down_btn-disabled');
        }

      })();
      return;
    }

  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll);
  upDownBtn.addEventListener('click', backToTop);
})();
/* end Up-Down button  */
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.matrix {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}


/* begin Up-Down button  */

.up_down_btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 80px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.up_down_btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #e9ebec;
}

.up_down_btn-show {
  display: block;
}

.up_down_btn-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0;
}


/* end Up-Down button  */
```

```html
<h1>Scroll down</h1>
<div class="matrix">
  <script>
    for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++) document.writeln(i)
  </script>
</div>
<!-- begin Up-Down button -->
<a class="up_down_btn" title="Наверх">&uarr;</a>
<!-- end Up-Down button -->
```

*Для использования брать только тот код, что внутри комментариев(begin/end), остальной здесь просто для демонстрации.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```js
  const goToButton = document.querySelector('.js-your-button-here');
  const bottomCoordinates = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  let destination = "bot";

  goToButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (destination === "bot") {
      window.scrollTo(0 , bottomCoordinates);
      destination = "top"
    } else if (destination === "top") {
      window.scrollTo(0 , 0);
      destination = "bot"
    }
  })
```

ИЛИ более сложную, но лучшую версию этого

```js
  // ищем кнопку по классу
  const goToButton = document.querySelector('.js-your-button-here');

  // высчитываем высоту документа с учетом скролла
  const bottomCoordinates = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

  // устанавливаем дэфолтное место назначение
  let destination = "bot";

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY > bottomCoordinates / 2) {
      // когда мы перешагнули половину страницы - меняем направление на "топ"
      // и поворачиваем кнопку со стрелкой вверх, чтобы пользователь понял
      goToButton.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
      destination = "top"
      
    } else {
      // если мы опять в верхней половине - возвращаем все назад
      // и снова поворачиваем кнопку
      goToButton.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
      destination = "bot"

    }
  })

  goToButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (destination === "bot") {
      // скроллим вниз
      window.scrollTo(0 , bottomCoordinates);

    } else if (destination === "top") {
      // скроллим вверх
      window.scrollTo(0 , 0);

    }
  });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ответ на русский язык или давайте ответы на английском аналоге.